# py.test parametrize `pytest.param` not found?

Tags: python, pytest

While trying to make unit tests (using py.test) more generic I am generating the test programatically. - I've a function that exports the arguments and the invariant that holds at the end of the test.

Now to keep things tidy I also wish to pass an ID for the test. Looking through the official(?) documentation for pytest I notice:

```
import pytest

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# ...

@pytest.mark.parametrize("a,b,expected", [
    pytest.param(datetime(2001, 12, 12), datetime(2001, 12, 11),
                 timedelta(1), id='forward'),
    pytest.param(datetime(2001, 12, 11), datetime(2001, 12, 12),
                 timedelta(-1), id='backward'),
])
def test_timedistance_v3(a, b, expected):
    diff = a - b
    assert diff == expected
```

at examples to show [different ways to parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#different-options-for-test-ids).

Above method is exactly what I wish to do (give arguments and also ID with each set of arguments): my function would just output a list of `pytest.param` objects. However when I ran the above snippet (or full one from pytest.org) I'm given the following error (also pycharm ide highlights this syntax error):

`E   AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'param'`

Is the documentation wrong? Am I missing something where I don't have the environment set up correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pytest.param` has only [recently been implemented](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/commit/e368fb4b29912fe618d523b2ca9197016738d7d6). To make use of it make sure you are using `py.test` version `3.1.0` or later.

```
pip install -U "pytest>=3.1.0"
```